# Why am I getting different output from password function?

Tags: passwords, mysql-5.1

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password - the documentation says that

```
mysql> SELECT PASSWORD('badpwd');
    -> '*AAB3E285149C0135D51A520E1940DD3263DC008C'
```

But I get:

```
 > SELECT PASSWORD('badpwd')
-> 7f84554057dd964b
```

MySQL version: 5.1.56-log through PHP extension MySQLi, Linux

Is it a mistake in docs?

Thanks!

Comment: I checked my MySQL and got the same password as the documentation. Do you have a function named pasword? Im not sure what version my mysql is but its the latest ubuntu release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a mistake in the documents. I just verified on my MySQL 5.1.x instance:

```
SELECT PASSWORD('badpwd');

PASSWORD('badpwd')-> *AAB3E285149C0135D51A520E1940DD3263DC008C
```

Would it be possible to see your full PHP example, to potentially better pinpoint the issue?

Comment: I don't have a PHP script. I run the SQL query in Adminer (http://www.adminer.org/; phpMyAdmin alternative; a database managemen tool).

Comment: It seems it's really an issue on just one machine. Thanks for confirmation!